# How to keep cookie when redirecting to different domain?

Tags: express, cookies, spotify

I am trying to make use of the Spotify API in an express.js application. I am running into some issues when following the authorization flow that can be found on the [Spotify Api docs](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization/code-flow/).

Spotify actually links [this](https://github.com/spotify/web-api-auth-examples/blob/master/authorization_code/app.js) guide for authentication using express that I have mainly been following.

I have been able to successfully request and gain authorization with the following route:

```js
app.get('/login', function(req, res) {

  var state = generateRandomString(16); // state parameter I provide Spotify API
  console.log('Original state (generated in /login): ', state);  // Original state (generated in /login):  UzLczCmKIKuzvIMP

  let options = {
    maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
    sameSite: 'lax',
    overwrite: true,
  }

  res.cookie('spotify_auth_state', state, options);
  console.log(`Cookie before redirecting to Oauth: ${JSON.stringify(res.cookies)}`);   // Cookie before redirecting to Oauth: undefined

  // your application requests authorization
  var scope = 'user-read-private user-read-email';
  res.redirect('https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?' +
    querystring.stringify({
      response_type: 'code',
      client_id: client_id,
      scope: scope,
      redirect_uri: redirect_uri,
      state: state
    }));
});
```

Make note of the state variable that I am storing in the cookies as `spotify_auth_state`.

Once authorization has been granted, the Spotify API redirects the client to a link that you provide in the Developer portal. In this case I use `localhost:3000/request_tokens` to redirect the client to my route to request tokens to actually make use of the API.

This is the following route that the Spotify Oauth redirects to:

```js
app.get('/request_tokens', function(req, res) {
  console.log();
  // your application requests refresh and access tokens
  // after checking the state parameter

  var code = req.query.code || null;
  var state = req.query.state || null;
  var storedState = req.cookies ? req.cookies['spotify_auth_state'] : null;
  console.log(`State sent from spotify (should match): ${state}`);   // State sent from spotify (should match): UzLczCmKIKuzvIMP
  console.log(`Saved state (as cookie): ${storedState}`);  // Saved state (as cookie): undefined
  console.log(`Cookies when redirected to /request_tokens: ${JSON.stringify(req.cookies)}`);  // Cookies when redirected to /request_tokens: {}

  if (state === null || state !== storedState) {
    res.redirect('/#' +
      querystring.stringify({
        error: 'state_mismatch',
        state: state,
        stored_state: storedState
      }));
  } else {
```

My issue is that I never get the `else' statement which is the goal. This is because, per Spotify documentation, my app `should compare the state parameter that it received in the redirection URI with the state parameter it originally provided to Spotify in the authorization URI. If there is a mismatch then your app should reject the request and stop the authentication flow`

The guide saves the 'state' variable in a cookie in the `/login` route when it is generated and then pulls it from the cookies once Spotify redirects to my `/request_tokens` route. However, when trying to find the cookie with I keep finding that it is undefined.

I assume it gets cleared because I am redirecting to a different domain (Spotify's authorization) so it is no longer there when Spotify redirects back to my local host. Can this 'state' variable be saved and checked via cookies or is there a better way to do this?